# How to create a mouse wheel event programmatically in gwt

Tags: java, gwt, mouseevent

I am writing testcases for my gwt project using gwt-test-utils.
I need to programmatically dispatch a mouse wheel event in google web toolkit.

`com.google.gwt.user.client.Event;`

i tried  this code

```
Event event = EventBuilder.create(Event.ONMOUSEWHEEL).build();      
Browser.dispatchEvent(myUIComponent,event );
```

The event is succesfully created and is fired.

I have added an event listener to listen to the mousewheel event

```
myUIComponent.addMouseWheelHandler(new MouseWheelHandler() {
        public void onMouseWheel(MouseWheelEvent event) {

            if (event.isNorth()) {

            } else {

            }

        }
    });
```

But when the event listener is excecuted, i get an error message when `event.isNorth()` is excecuted.

the stack trace is given below

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Abstract method 'DOMImpl.eventGetMouseWheelVelocityY()' is not patched by com.googlecode.gwt.test.internal.AutomaticPatcher
at com.google.gwt.dom.client.DOMImpl.eventGetMouseWheelVelocityY(DOMImpl.java)
at com.google.gwt.dom.client.NativeEvent$.getMouseWheelVelocityY$(NativeEvent.java:175)
at com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.MouseWheelEvent.getDeltaY(MouseWheelEvent.java:73)
at com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.MouseWheelEvent.isNorth(MouseWheelEvent.java:84)
at com.rubirules.uibuilder.client.TimePicker$4.onMouseWheel(TimePicker.java:227)
at com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.MouseWheelEvent.dispatch(MouseWheelEvent.java:100)
at com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.MouseWheelEvent.dispatch(MouseWheelEvent.java:23)
at com.google.web.bindery.event.shared.EventBus.dispatchEvent(EventBus.java:40)
at com.google.web.bindery.event.shared.SimpleEventBus.doFire(SimpleEventBus.java:193)
at com.google.web.bindery.event.shared.SimpleEventBus.fireEvent(SimpleEventBus.java:88)
at com.google.gwt.event.shared.HandlerManager.fireEvent(HandlerManager.java:127)
at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Widget.fireEvent(Widget.java:129)
at com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.DomEvent.fireNativeEvent(DomEvent.java:116)
at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Widget.onBrowserEvent(Widget.java:177)
at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.ValueBoxBase.onBrowserEvent(ValueBoxBase.java:252)
at com.googlecode.gwt.test.utils.events.Browser.dispatchEventWithBubble(Browser.java:969)
at com.googlecode.gwt.test.utils.events.Browser.dispatchEventInternal(Browser.java:921)
at com.googlecode.gwt.test.utils.events.Browser.dispatchEventsInternal(Browser.java:946)
at com.googlecode.gwt.test.utils.events.Browser.dispatchEvent(Browser.java:313)
at com.rubirules.uibuilder.client.TimePickerTest.testHoursScrollUp(TimePickerTest.java:30)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:31)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:73)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:46)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:180)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:41)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:173)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:31)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:220)
at com.googlecode.gwt.test.internal.junit.GwtBlockJUnit4ClassRunner.run(GwtBlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:27)
at com.googlecode.gwt.test.internal.junit.AbstractGwtRunner.run(AbstractGwtRunner.java:47)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

This works fine when the event is fired fron actual mouse wheel event.
Is there something wrong in my event creation.
Suggest the best method for creating events manually.

Answer (score 2):

Dispatch an event with mousewheel movement up:

```
Event ev = EventBuilder.create(Event.ONMOUSEWHEEL).setMouseX(KeyCodes.KEY_DOWN).build();
MouseWheelVelocity evnt = new MouseWheelVelocity(ev);
```

Answer (score 0):

You must manually patch this method, as it does not seem to be included.

See http://code.google.com/p/gwt-test-utils/issues/detail?id=156 for details.

You will need to create a Patcher object which mocks up the value you want returned from DOMImpl.eventGetMouseWheelVelocityY().  This may be problematic since DOMImpl is deferred-bound to multiple runtime targets, and I'm not familiar enough with gwt-test-utils to tell you whether you can patch it or not.

If you can't patch DOMImpl, instead patch MouseWheelEvent.isNorth().

Comment: 'MouseWheelEvent.isNorth()' is working when the mouse event is fired by using the mouse.  it is not working when i try to create an event manually using code
i tried  'EventBuilder.create(Event.ONMOUSEWHEEL).build();' and 'Browser.mouseWheel(uicomponent)' but both doesnt work.

Comment: Your problem is in gwt-test-utils.

It requires mocking all native mathods using Patcher object (see link in my answer).  It's blowing up because your test utility doesn't have a patched DOMImpl class.  You would probably have an easier time patching the mouse event instead of DOMImpl though...

Comment: I patched the method `MouseWheelEventPatcher.getMouseWheelVelocityY()`
but it says that only static methods can be patched and i get
`com.googlecode.gwt.test.exceptions.GwtTestPatchException: @com.googlecode.gwt.test.patchers.PatchMethod has to be static : 'com.rubirules.uibuilder.client.MouseWheelEventPatcher.getMouseWheelVelocityY()'`

Comment: Weak.  That really sucks.

About all you can do now is to create a spring method like: static boolean isNorth(MouseEvent e){return e.isNorth();}, so you can patch it instead.

Comment: Do I need to change `com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.MouseWheelEvent` class for this?

Please provide more details. I am new to this kind of things.

Comment: After using gwt-test-utils at work, might I suggest you upgrade versions / report your version?  With 0.43, we are able to simulate all sorts of browser events and make native calls.

Comment: As for the change, if you need it, is to move your call of e.isNorth() inside a static method somewhere you can override.  Then, you can write your Patcher object for your delegate method.  Basically, if you can't patch the source, use a method that you can patch as a proxy.